# Instance of ViewController returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the instance of `HomeViewController` as follows. I am trying to access its properties, which hold dataset. However, whenever I check in the other class -`GlobalFunctions` all of the `HomeViewController` properties are nil.

**HomeViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pTempElements;
+(HomeViewController*) homeDataInstance;
```

**HomeViewController.m**

```
+(HomeViewController*) homeDataInstance {
    static HomeViewController *dataInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!dataInstance){
            dataInstance = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return dataInstance;
}

-(void)loadFromURL {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *PRODUCT_ALL_URL = [settings objectForKey: @"PRODUCT_ALL_URL"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:PRODUCT_ALL_URL parameters:nil progress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
        if(responseObject != NULL) {
            ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]init];
            for ( id jsonItem in responseObject)
            {
                dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
                [self.pElements addObject:dicItem];

            }
            self.pTempElements = pElements;
            [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    }];
}
```

**GlobalFunctions.m**

```
HomeViewController *restaurantData = [HomeViewController homeDataInstance];
// the following is nil
NSLog(@"%@", restaurantData.pTempElements);
```

`restaurantData` is all nil as follows in the `GlobalFunctions` class.

[image]

Comment: try this line : dataInstance = [[self alloc] init];

Comment: is your  restaurantData also nil ?

Comment: did you assign value to pTempElements because initial value will be nil until you not assign .

Comment: `restaurantData` is not nil, it has HomeViewController object.

Comment: yes, `pTempElements` assigned already, it gets data from the service.

Comment: then you need to assign value like same and check : if(!dataInstance){
            dataInstance = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
           pTempElements = @"Test"
        }

Comment: add that code in question .where you assigned that vaue ?

Comment: It is URL call via AFNetworking, I am getting the data and display it on the collectionView. CollectionView datasource is pTempElements.

Comment: if you make async call then this value also nil until you data not come .

Comment: First pTempElements gets the data and then when I click an item to add my order list, I hold only item id, and then when I am trying to access the item description, I am calling the GlobalFunctions call.

Comment: yes that is the problem try to create  instance in appdelgate for test before access this property .

Comment: yes add that code for how to assign that property and where you assign that property .

Comment: I have added that portion of the code, please see update

Comment: when will you called this loadFromURL ?

Comment: in `ViewWillAppear` method

Comment: Share HomeViewController.m, please.

Comment: try to check navigation array it is there or not ?

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet and screenshot you have shared, we can clearly see that your instance is successfully created.

The property values are showing nil because you have not assigned any values to them. Try assigning initial values to those properties.

For UI related properties either you should map them in your .xib or .storyboard file so that they are initialised with some value or initialize them in your code somewhere before using them.

e.g In your case: productCollectionView and categoryCollectionView

Similarly incase of other properties.

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: I am getting the data and display it on the collectionView. CollectionView datasource is pTempElements. and then I call GlobalFunctions call.

Comment: You mean you are at HomeViewController first and then in GlobalFunctions.m you are trying to access same HomeViewController instance which already exists?

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Then you should access that storyboard first and then retrieve the same viewcontroller from that storyboard. Try accessing it from following code:

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:nil];

 HomeViewController
 * restaurantData
 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController
"];

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with singleton object. try this class method:

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance{

    static storeViewController *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[storeViewController alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this!

```
#import "WebService.h"
static WebService *webService;
@implementation WebService
+(WebService *)sharedWebService{
    if(!webService){
        webService = [[WebService alloc] init];
    }
    return webService;
}
```

In .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface WebService : NSObject

+(WebService *)sharedWebService;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pTempElements;
```

Comment: Please check my updated question, it is exactly what you have proposed.

Comment: @hotspring you declared singlton object so i don't think need to create separate object if you want to access do like this you can direct access with [[WebService sharedWebService]pTempElements];

Answer (score 0):

**Try this funtion using block**

```
-(void)loadFromURLWithCallback:(void(^)(NSArray *pTempElements))callback {
    // add this condition if your dont need to refresh data
    if (self.pElements) {
        callback(self.pElements)
        [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
        return;
    }
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *PRODUCT_ALL_URL = [settings objectForKey: @"PRODUCT_ALL_URL"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:PRODUCT_ALL_URL parameters:nil progress: nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull operation, id responseObject) {
        if(responseObject != NULL) {
            ProductData *dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]init];
            for ( id jsonItem in responseObject)
            {
                dicItem = [[ProductData alloc]initWithDictionary:jsonItem];
                [self.pElements addObject:dicItem];

            }
            self.pTempElements = pElements;
            [self.productCollectionView reloadData];
            callback(elf.pTempElements)

        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        callback(nil);

    }];
}
```

**calling of method**

```
[self loadFromURLWithCallback:^(NSArray *pTempElements) {

    }];
```